# two back slash in SQL procedure with Regular expression

Tags: mysql, escaping, regexp-like

i'm working on a SQL procedure where i came across a Regular expression which contains this piece -

```
REGEXP '\\s*count\\s*\\('
```

i do not understand why there are two backslash ? what can be inferred from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is processed at multiple levels.

It's the escape prefix in regular expressions: it makes special characters like `.` and `(` be treated literally, and is used to created escape sequences like `\s` (which means any whitespace character).

But it's also the escape prefix in string literals, used for things like `\n` (newline) and `\b` (backspace). So in order for the regular expression character to get a literal backslash, you need to escape the backslash itself.

This is common in many programming languages, although a few have "raw string literals" where escape sequences are not processed, specifically to avoid having to double the slashes so much.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the clarification.