Confusion using regexp in mysql to match a string
I'm new to regexp and mysql but I'm trying to match the following:
SELECT 'abc: bcd' REGEXP '(abc):?\s?b'

This seems to work in a couple of online browser regex simulators but not in mysql.
I couldn't find any similar questions but I may be missing the right keywords to find my answer
Any help would be greatly appreiciated!
SELECT 'abc: bcd' REGEXP '(abc):?\s?'

This seems to work without the last 'b' but I want to specifiy a word following this part to look for
Tested using https://regexr.com/
and https://www.regextester.com/112633
using /.../ig

Perhaps this page is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558172/mysql-regexp-whitespace-s

What is your version of MySQL? SELECT VERSION();

Your regex is working plese check the changes:
SELECT ('abc: bcd' REGEXP '(abc):?\\s?b') as match_regex;

SELECT ('abc: bcd' REGEXP '(abc):?\\s?') as match_regex;

Better solution:
-- basic matching
SELECT ('abc: bcd' REGEXP '\\w{3}\:\\s*\\w{3}') as match_regex;

-- Regex lookahead & lookbehind 
SELECT ('abc: bcd' REGEXP '(?<=\\w{3})\:\\s*(?=\\w{3})') as match_regex;

Sample code: db<>fiddle

Yeah this does it, If you don't mind me asking how the double backslash makes this work, it seems as if it would simply search for a '' in the string instead

Please check solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599917/two-back-slash-in-sql-procedure-with-regular-expression
